Нужна ли запятая после указания должности в данном предложении?
Иван Иванов, официальный представитель данной структуры (?) сообщил:

Правильно:
Иван Иванов, официальный представитель данной структуры, сообщил...
Пояснение

Обособляется распространенное приложение в постпозиции (имя собственное + приложение) по общему правилу: Розенталь § 19. Обособленные приложения, пункт 1

Сравнить: Официальный представитель данной структуры ИВАН Иванов сообщил...


В позиции приложение + имя собственное вариант без обособления является основным (если нет утоняющего значения).

Пример у Розенталя (пункт 5): Поручик царской армии Василий Данилович Дибич пробирался из немецкого плена на родину (Фед.).

